# Align Div using CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been struggling to get the below layout working using flexbox:
[image]

I tried the below HTML and CSS

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">6</div>
</div>

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is the result which is incorrect:
[image]

Any ideas/suggestions on how to achieve the first layout?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items , Look at order property

Comment: use `order` if you want to list on custom order[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-order elements within a flexbox you need to use `flex-order` (order). In specific:

```
/* Element with number 1 */
.flex-container :nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

/* Element with number 2 */
.flex-container :nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}

/* Element with number 3 */
.flex-container :nth-child(3) {
  order: 6;
}

/* Element with number 4 */
.flex-container :nth-child(4) {
  order: 5;
}

/* Element with number 5 */
.flex-container :nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

/* Element with number 6 */
.flex-container :nth-child(6) {
  order: 1;
}
```

Last but not least, with the code provided, you still dont get the wanted result but boxes aligned as:

```
#6 #5
#1 #4
#2 #3
```

This is because you applied `flex-direction: column;`. You need to remove the line.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
  min-height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(3) {
  order: 6;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(4) {
  order: 5;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(5) {
  order: 4;
}

.flex-container :nth-child(6) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
  <div class="flex-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: They never do, it's extremely infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to achieve. You can change order of elements in HTML to have what you want. If you wan to keep HTML unchanged, you can use css property `order`.